# erst mal vs vorerst vs fürs Erste

Tags: meaning

I have the following sentence heard in the Kitz TV series:

> Danke, erst mal.

Context: A police investigator thanks a girl after asking her some questions about the death of a young rich friend of hers.

I know the sentence means "Thanks for now". Is there any difference in meaning between "Danke, erst mal", "Danke vorerst" and "Danke fürs Erste" ?

Comment: No, those are synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

They are more or less synonymous.

If I really want to find a difference: "vorerst" can have a meaning more like "provisionally".